# C# OOP practice confusion regarding inheritance

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, interface, radix

I am reading one of my C# programming course material.  I understand the code itself, but I don't quite understand why the tutor organises the class this way.

```
namespace GradeBook
{



public delegate void GradeAddedDelegate(object sender, EventArgs args);
public class NamedObject 
{
    public NamedObject(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public interface IBook
{
    void AddGrade(double grade);
    Statistics GetStatistics();
    string Name { get; }
    event GradeAddedDelegate GradeAdded;
}

public abstract class Book : NamedObject, IBook
{
    public Book(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public abstract event GradeAddedDelegate GradeAdded;
    public abstract void AddGrade(double grade);
    public abstract Statistics GetStatistics();
}

public class DiskBook : Book
{
    public DiskBook(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }

    public override event GradeAddedDelegate GradeAdded;

    public override void AddGrade(double grade)
    {
        using(var writer = File.AppendText($"{Name}.txt"))
        {                
            writer.WriteLine(grade);
            if(GradeAdded != null)
            {
                GradeAdded(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    public override Statistics GetStatistics()
    {
        var result = new Statistics();

        using(var reader = File.OpenText($"{Name}.txt"))
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                var number = double.Parse(line);
                result.Add(number);
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The code snippet above is a GradeBook for normal students.

1. class `NameObject` defines a property `Name` and an initializer, which is easy to understand.
2. He put all method in an interface `IBook`, and there is another class called `Book`, which is inherited from `NameObject` class and interface `IBook`.  I am assuming he deliberately separate properties and methods, event. Is this correct?
3. In the `Book` class,  the initializer `public Book(string name) : base(name)`.  I know the base is defining a reference type.  I am getting a bit confused with the `name` parameter.  Does it refer to the property `Name` in `NameObject`?
4. DiskBook is a subclass of Book, the initializer `public Book(string name) : base(name)` is passing a reference `name` as the last one.  Does the `name` here refers to the `name` property in NameObject as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _" I don't quite understand why the tutor organises the class this way."_ - it's because he needs to cram everything from "interface" to "abstract class" to "derived class" including "delegates", "events" and "properties" into one small halfway decent example code.

Comment: Unfortunately, he's also crammed in a potential race condition in how that delegate is null checked/invoked.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough for the educational purpose.  I was wondering why?  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2. Logically, a lot of things could be a `NamedObject`.  He's saying a `Book` is an `IBook`, and also a `NamedObject`.  Imagine adding a `Person` class.  That `Person` would be a `NamedObject`, but not an `IBook`.  So you can reuse the base class without tying it to a `Book`
3. using `: base(name)` says `call the constructor on the base class with this parameter`.  So you can be sure that `NamedObject`'s constructor will be called with the string value, setting the `Name` property.  Excluding the `: base(name)` from the `Book` constructor will cause a compiler error, as the base class does not have a parameterless constructor.
4. In the same manner, `DiskBook` is using `: base(name)` to call the constructor on `Book`, which in turn calls the constructor on `NamedObject`.